# count columns with same value/string for each row in r

Tags: r

Say my data(imaginary) ,a data frame is as follows :

```
 > head(data)
                       mpg_H cyl_G disp_G  
    Mazda RX4         TRUE   TRUE     TRUE     
    Mazda RX4 Wag     TRUE   FALSE    FALSE     
    Datsun 710        FALSE  FALSE    FALSE     
    Hornet 4 Drive    FALSE  TRUE     TRUE     
    Hornet Sportabout TRUE   TRUE     TRUE     
    Valiant           TRUE   TRUE     FALSE
```

Now, I want to have 2 added columns which will count the number of TRUE and FALSE for each row as below :

```
> head(data)
                   mpg_H cyl_G disp_G  count_TRUE count_FALSE
Mazda RX4         TRUE   TRUE     TRUE     3        0
Mazda RX4 Wag     TRUE   FALSE    FALSE    1        2
Datsun 710        FALSE  FALSE    FALSE    0        3
Hornet 4 Drive    FALSE  TRUE     TRUE     2        1
Hornet Sportabout TRUE   TRUE     TRUE     3        0
Valiant           TRUE   TRUE     FALSE    2        1
```

Please help me with a solution in R.

Answer (score 4):

Try `rowSums` or `Reduce`

```
count_TRUE <- rowSums(df) # Or count_TRUE <- Reduce(`+`, df)
df[c("count_TRUE", "count_FALSE")] <- cbind(count_TRUE, ncol(df) - count_TRUE)
df
#                   mpg_H cyl_G disp_G count_TRUE count_FALSE
# Mazda RX4          TRUE  TRUE   TRUE          3           0
# Mazda RX4 Wag      TRUE FALSE  FALSE          1           2
# Datsun 710        FALSE FALSE  FALSE          0           3
# Hornet 4 Drive    FALSE  TRUE   TRUE          2           1
# Hornet Sportabout  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE          3           0
# Valiant            TRUE  TRUE  FALSE          2           1
```

Comment: Thanks David, that is exactly what I wanted. Would you be kind enough to also explain how it works for a particular value. Say for example I want to count only those columns which have a value of 4 for each row.

Comment: It converts `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0` and then sums them up. If you want to count all the columns with `4` you could do `rowSums(df == 4)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and `sum`.

```
df$count_TRUE <- apply(df, 1,sum); 
df$count_FALSE <- (ncol(df)-1)-df$count_TRUE;
```